# How can I correct error in Web Site Configuration Tool?

Tags: authentication, visual-studio-2012, configuration, membership

I am attempting to implement the Asp.net Login controls on my web application.  I have run the aspnet_sqlreg and successfully installed the tables in my SQL Server Express development database.  Now, however, I have been unable to use the Web Site Configuration Tool to direct the Login controls to my database.  When I click the Security tab, I see the following message:

> *There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused by an invalid server name or credentials, or by insufficient permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where you can choose a new data store.

> The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Database 'C:\USERS\ACER\ONEDRIVE\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2012\WEBSITES\PPM\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF' cannot be upgraded because its non-release version (603) is not supported by this version of SQL Server. You cannot open a database that is incompatible with this version of sqlservr.exe. You must re-create the database. Could not open new database 'C:\USERS\ACER\ONEDRIVE\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2012\WEBSITES\PPM\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted. An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\acer\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\PPM\App_Data\aspnetdb.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.*

Since I do not intend to use the aspnetdb.mdf file, I renamed it.  I also deleted aspnetdb.mdf from the list of Data Connections in VS 2012, but I find that the connection is automatically regenerated.  The Application tab on the Web Site Configuration Tool shows "Existing application settings: 0."  On the Provider tab, when I click either of the two links, I see only one provider available, AspNetSqlProvider, which is preselected.  When I click the Test link, I get the error message:

> *Could not establish a connection to the database.
> If you have not yet created the SQL Server database, exit the Web Site Administration tool, use the aspnet_regsql command-line utility to create and configure the database, and then return to this tool to set the provider.*

I would like to configure my web app to write and read membership data in the tables in my SQL Server Express database.  Any guidance will be appreciated.